# why there is a flickering of old image if I change vew_port for canvas before calling present?

Tags: rust, 2d, sdl-2

I wrote a small demo in Rust/SDL, which do fade-in and fade-out of the image, plus some occasional random specs. It was super smooth and good, cranking up to 250 fps.

I decided to add change to `canvas.set_viewport` on each frame with random dimensions. Basically, the same streaming texture (which filled with new tone or noise on each frame) is drawn at random location with random size.

I found there is an (unexplainable) flickering for already rendered rectangles.

I've tried to screencapture it, but on video there is no flickering. I used a normal camera (60fps) and there was no flickering. I've used high-speed mode in my phone and I got flickering recorded, but it looked very different from what I see.

What is it?

The code: https://github.com/amarao/sdl_random/tree/c4757190712f0a996c2aba88b105462942d4ca27/src

Non-flickering screencapture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zud9Hjwltxk

Flickering video (hi-speed):  https://youtu.be/rVZki9COuZ0

The second question: if this is some kind of 'underfined behaviour' from my GPU (nvidia), why is it so? Is changing viewport on-fly supported?

Edit: I changed call to `set_viewport` into a `rect` parameter for `canvas.copy`:

```
canvas.copy(
   &texture, None,
   sdl2::rect::Rect::new(
      new_x as i32,
      new_y as i32,
      new_width,
      new_height
  )
).unwrap();
```

but result is absolutely the same.

Comment: Why does this question have the [tag:opengl] tag?

Comment: From the description it sounds like you're drawing more and more rectangles on screen without clearing? Then result is to be expected because of double buffering. You can use intermediate render texture as your single accumulation buffer - i.e. create render texture the same same as screen, draw your rectangles there, and at the end of each frame render this texture to screen.

Comment: keltar, can you explain it a bit? Why drawing more and more rectangles without clearing should cause flickering?

Comment: Because you have two buffers - one is on screen, and one you draw into. When `present` is called, buffers are swapped. You start rendering with empty buffers, render first rectangle, swap; now your buffers contain rectangles `[1]` and `[]`. You render second rectangle, but render buffer is now empty (previous backbuffer with rectangle 1 is on screen), so buffers are `[2]` and `[1]`. Swap. You render third rectangle, buffers are `[1, 3]` and `[2]`. They will never converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to *double buffering* ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering)). The render system uses two buffers in-tandem: one is being presented while the other is being written to. You can verify that this is enabled in SDL2 by checking [`video_system.gl_attrs().double_buffer()`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.34.3/sdl2/video/gl_attr/struct.GLAttr.html#method.double_buffer).

You are drawing iteratively on the same buffers without clearing or redrawing on them. So one buffer will have everything from even frames drawn on them, and the other will have the odd. So, the flickering is caused by swapping between them when they have wildly diverging contents.